# How to retrieve User Profiles that have been modified recently

Tags: user-profile-service

We have a process that extracts User Profiles from the User Profile Service Application

The problem is we need only the user Profiles that have been modified in the last one week

How should we approach it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can use [UserProfileManager.GetChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilechangecollection.aspx) method and test if the change made is before 7 days using [ProfileBaseChange.EventTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.profilebasechange.eventtime.aspx) property

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // TODO: Set Your target SPSite Url
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("Your Site Url"))
    {
        try
        {

        SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);

        //initialize user profile config manager object
        UserProfileManager profileConfigManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

            UserProfileChangeCollection collection = profileConfigManager.GetChanges();
            foreach (UserProfileChange change in collection)
            {
                // Filter user Profiles that have been modified in the last one week
                if (change.EventTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n*-- Change made this week --*\n");

                    Console.WriteLine("AccountName : " + change.AccountName);
                    Console.WriteLine("ChangeType : " + change.ChangeType);
                    Console.WriteLine("EventTime : " + change.EventTime);
                    Console.WriteLine("Id : " + change.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("ObjectType : " + change.ObjectType); 
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n*-- Old Change --*\n");

                    Console.WriteLine("AccountName : " + change.AccountName);
                    Console.WriteLine("ChangeType : " + change.ChangeType);
                    Console.WriteLine("EventTime : " + change.EventTime);
                    Console.WriteLine("Id : " + change.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("ObjectType : " + change.ObjectType);

                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And the result :

[image]